# Creating Google Sign Incomplete (OAuth2 not created)

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-signin

My intention is to implement google sign-in in an Android project. I followed the instruction from [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

But, in step [Configure A Google Api Project](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#configure_a_project), after I clicked "Configure A Project", and then choosing a new project (or existing project, it doesn't matter), it will then go straight to "You're all set". Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGatQ.jpg

It doesn't asks for other information like the package name, SHA1, etc.

I implemented a google sign in last year for another project, and it asks for those information.
It created an automatic OAuth2 client for google sign in. 
And now, it doesn't create OAuth2.

I've read many tutorials about this, and all of them explain that Google will create an automatic OAuth2 for google sign in.

Is it maybe breaking? Or should I create the Oauth2 for google sign in manually, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Trenton_M, Thanks. But I knew that when I uploaded the image. Sorry, I didn't blur it out. It's a test project, it's sort of useless.. :)

Comment: Okay.  Up to you.  Put it back in if it's not an issue.